# old old TEX files

Tags: compiling

The following is an old code. I have many others, but this is the shortest one. It was certainly compiling at the time it was written. Is there a way to recover it in pdf format?
Thanks

```
\documentstyle [12pt]{letter}    
\textwidth 160mm
\textheight 240mm
\topmargin -1cm
\oddsidemargin -0.5mm
\pagestyle{empty}
\textwidth 160mm
\textheight 240mm
\topmargin -1cm
\oddsidemargin -0.5mm
\pagestyle{empty}
\input mathdef.sty
\begin{document}
\signature{ (Francesco Pannaria)}
\address{Francesco Pannaria \\ Via Labicana 110, \\ 00184 Roma.}
\begin{letter}{Al prof. C. Rubbia, \\~~~~Direttore Generale CERN, \\~~~~CH 1211 
Ginevra 23, \\~~~~Svizzera.  \\ Roma, 18 settembre 1992.}
\opening{Carissimo prof. Rubbia,}
Sono in attesa di una Sua risposta alla mia lettera del 24 giugno 1992.
\closing{Cordialit\`a,} 
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apart from the need to track down `mathdef.sty` I don't see an issue here (LaTeX2e has a LaTeX2.09 compatibility system).

Answer (score 16):

the file doesn't use the missing mathdef.tex file so if you comment out that line it runs without error to produce

[image]

Comment: Fortunately they didn't use `\today` so we know how old it is.

Comment: what about if in other codes I have formulas and tables?

Comment: @ClaudioCardella there is a file of that name in the zip file here https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/ualberta-math-stat-templates/thesis_template.zip and that's the only one google found, so it may be that file. but if `mathdef.sty` was just your local math definitions from that time and never public then you need to find (or recreate) them. But basically latex is designed so that 30 year old documents still work so i would not expect any problems,

Comment: Thanks a lot David! Especially for retrieving the missing file. Now everything works!!!! Your help was highly appreciated.